# Coffeescript clear text in in text box on click

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to clear text from a simple text box when a radio button is clicked. Here is my coffeescript...

```
  $("#selection_single").click ->
    $("#from_date_text").text("Single Date")
    $(".multiple_dates").hide()
    $('#to_date').text("")
```

...and here is the text box...

```
<input id="to_date" name="to_date" type="text" />
```

The other JS in this particular snippet works, just not the one for to_date. Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<input>` elements don't have contents.

You want to set the *value* of the `<input>`, using the `.val()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You nailed it SLaks! Here is my finished code...

```
 $("#selection_single").click ->
    $("#from_date_text").text("Single Date")
    $(".multiple_dates").hide()
    $('#to_date').val("")
```